# In DGET function, how to use multiple cell ranges as search criteria?

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

I am using the [`DGET`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_DGET_function) function in LibreOffice. I have the first table as shown below (top). I want to make second table (bottom). I can use DGET function where *Database* is the cell range containing top table and *Database Field* is "Winner".

Is it possible to have different cell ranges in *Search Criteria*, so that for each cell in row for Case #1 can have separate formula with a different search criteria as given in the first row of bottom table?

If I have to use separate continuous cell ranges for search criteria, then there would be [n*Chances] cell ranges, where n=total number of cases (~150 in my case) and Chances = possible number of Chance# (50 in my case).

```
Case | Chance#  |  Winner
-------------------------
1    |   7      |    Joe
1    |   9      |    Emil
1    |   10     |    Harry
1    |   11     |    Kate
2    |   1      |    Tom
2    |   3      |    Jerry
2    |   4      |    Mike
2    |   7      |    John

Case  |Chance#|Chance#|Chance#|Chance#|Chance#|Chance#|Chance#|Chance#|Chance#|Chance#|Chance#| 
      |="=1"  |="=2"  |="=3"  |="=4"  |="=5"  |="=6"  |="=7"  |="=8"  |="=9"  |="=10" |="=11" | ---- |="=50"  
 1    |       |       |       |       |       |       | Joe   |       |Emil   |Harry  | Kate  | ---- | 
 2    | Tom   |       |Jerry  |Mike   |       |       | John  |       |       |       |       | ---- |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, you need to change your approach, instead of using DGET, I'm using a rather more complex method:

Considering your example:

```
       A       B       C       D       
1      #       Case    Chance# Winner
2      1       1       7       Joe
3      2       1       9       Emil
4      3       1       10      Harry
5      4       1       11      Kate
6      5       2       1       Tom
7      6       2       3       Jerry
8      7       2       4       Mike
9      8       2       7       John
10      
11      Case\Chance#      1      2      3      4
12            1
13            2         Tom            Jerry      Mike
```

I use the following:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$9=$A12)*($C$2:$C$9=B$11)*($A$2:$A$9))> 0,INDEX($D$2:$D$9,SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$9=$A12)*($C$2:$C$9=B$11)*($A$2:$A$9))),"")
```

Let's ignore the IF, and focus on the real deal here:

First, Get the row that matches your condition, $B$2:$B$9=$A12 and $C$2:$C$9=B$11 will result in a TRUE/FALSE arrays, multiply them to get a 0/1 array with only a single 1 for the match, now multiply by the ID to get the row number in your table.
SUMPRODUCT will get you a single value (the row) from the result array.
Finally use index to retrieve the desired value.

The IF statement tests if a match do exist (SUMPRODUCT > 0), to filter out the cell with no match.